# How to extend the klee (llvm) build system?

Tags: build, klee

### Context

I am working on a klee (http://klee.llvm.org) fork and want to clean up our repository to separate our stuff from the "canonical" klee code. Anyway, I'm having trouble understanding/extending the build system.

### Problem

The directory structure in `/lib/` looks like this

```
Basic/
Core/
Support/
Expr/
Solver/
Module/
Mine/
```

`Mine` was just added by me, so far we threw everything in `Core` and I am moving it to `Mine`. How do I tell the build system to do this properly?

### My attempt

Being unable to figure this out on my own, I edited `/lib/Makefile`:

```
LEVEL=..

PARALLEL_DIRS=Basic Support Expr Solver Module Core Mine

include $(LEVEL)/Makefile.common
```

and copied the `/lib/Core/Makefile` to `/lib/Mine/Makefile` while changing `LIBRARYNAME=kleeCore` to `LIBRARYNAME=kleeMine`.

#### Caveat

I have a feeling that this is not the proper way to do it, and I should rather modify some configure script or something. Also it does not link (it compiles, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague just told me how to get it to link, which is by modifying `/tools/klee/Makefile`

```
USEDLIBS = kleeCore.a kleeModule.a kleaverSolver.a kleaverExpr.a kleeSupport.a kleeBasic.a kleeMine.a
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the way you are supposed to do this. But it seems to work. So if there are no better suggestions in a reasonable time, I'll keep this solution.